# SSIS variable defined by other variables not updating

Tags: sql, variables, ssis

In my SSIS package I have a variable (called SQL) that holds a dynamically created query.
The value of this query is defined by 2 other variables at run time.

For a reason that I have not been able to figure out, the variables value is not changing during run time :-(.
I used breakpoints and watches to check the exact value if the SQL variable and the 2 defining variables. What I see is that the 2 variables have the values I expect but the SQL variable keeps it's original version (and ends up running that way too).

This is the definition of the SQL variable:

```
"select *
from tbl1
where Date_Created>= to_date('"+
reverse(right(reverse(
(DT_WSTR, 20 )DATEADD( "Month", -3, (DT_DATE)@[User::StartDate])),10))
 +"', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
and 
Date_Created <=  to_date('"+
reverse(right(reverse(
(DT_WSTR, 20 )DATEADD( "Month", 3, (DT_DATE)@[User::EndDate])),10))
 +"', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What about the "Evaluate as Expression" being set to true or false on your SQL variable?

Comment: @rvphx, I've tried both settings but have not had the expected results :-(

Comment: I had a similar problems in an sp of mine. If one of those statements `reverse(right(reverse((DT_WSTR, 20 )DATEADD( "Month", -3,(DT_DATE)@[User::StartDate])),10))` evaluates to NULL then the whole query can be nulled. If the expreesion evaluates to null, your original SQL is used.

Comment: Try putting the whole thing `reverse(right(reverse(
(DT_WSTR, 20 )DATEADD( "Month", -3, (DT_DATE)@[User::StartDate])),10))` for both statements inside a variable and see what it evaluates to.

Comment: Same situation. I was about to post my question but then realized there already exists one. Any ideas would help. Expressions are pretty simple and obvious and they evaluate fine but during run time old values are used, I tried even rebuilding the package before running still the same situation. _I wonder if the project or solution saves the temp values of the variables in a cache or something_. **SSRS** gives similar trouble not showing refreshed or updated data, in that case we have to go to the project folder and delete xxx.data file and then it will re-import data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem and it ended up being a type cast issue in my expression.

User variable "tableName" is type String. User variable "myID" is type Int32. User variable "theQry" is type String.  EvaluateAsExpression = true and this was my expression:

```
"select *
from "+ (DT_STR, 5,1252) @[User::tableName] +
"WHERE id = "+ (DT_STR, 5,1252) @[User::myID]
```

I could see in the Watch panel that the value of "tableName" and "myID" were updating but "theQry" never did.

As soon as I removed the cast function on user variable "tableName", "theQry" began updating.

```
"select * from "+ @[User::tableName] + "WHERE id = "+ (DT_STR, 5,1252) @[User::myID]
```